# SPA Design & Routing: AngularJS, TaffyDB, & ExpressJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, routes

I have been using AngularJS for a few months now.  I have been using a Java backend for all of my AngularJS applications.  Now I'd like to learn how to program full-stack JavaScript applications.  I've never programmed in NodeJS.

The current design of my app has Angular taking care of all the routing, which is what I am most comfortable with.  However, I am not sure if that is good design when using NodeJS and Express on the backend.  In the past, my backend has been responsible for exposing a REST API that my frontend could leverage, and manipulating JSON data.  I didn't use it for anything else.

**This is how Angular is managing the routing in my full-stack JS app**

```
(function()
{
    angular
        .module('passGen', [
            'ui.router',
            'ngAnimate',
            'passGen.generator',
            'passGen.registration',
            'passGen.tabs',
            'passGen.main'
        ])
        .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
        {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

            $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                    url: '/home',
                    templateUrl: 'partials/main.html'
                })
                .state('registration', {
                    url: '/register',
                    templateUrl: 'partials/registration.html'
                })
                .state('products', {
                    url: '/products',
                });
        }]);
})();
```

I want to add user registration functionality to the application.  This is where TaffyDB and Node come into play.  I'd like the backend to maintain and serve all of the user registration data in order to avoid overloading the frontend.

Right now all I'm trying to do is post some data in NodeJS to the `/products` route, but it's not doing anything.  This is reflected in the comments.

**`server.js`**

```
(function()
{
    // modules
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var TAFFY = require('taffy');
    var app = express();

    app.use(express.static('src/app'));

    var products = TAFFY([{
        'item':1,
        'name':'Shark'
    }]);

    // I don't think this is necessary
    app.get('/#/home', function(req, res)
    {
        res.sendFile(path.join('/index.html'));
    });

    // Not doing anything, also doesn't work with the '/products' path
    app.post('/#/products', function(req, res)
    {
        res.send(products);
        console.log(products);
    });

    app.listen(8878);
})();
```

Perhaps I need to take a deeper look at [ExpressJS routing documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html), or refine my Google queries.

I have some questions:

1. Should I use AngularJS or ExpressJS to handle the routing?
2. If I can use AngularJS for the routing, then should I be able to use ExpressJS to handle HTTP requests?
3. Why isn't  `app.post` working in `server.js`?

Comment: You are doing some confusion. Use Node.js to route only backend calls, like API to give and manage data for your frontend app. In Angular (frontend) instead you will do the routes to navigate the app. So for example when you will be in /products with your browser Angular will call /api/products in Node to get the data to build the products page.